# morgan.format is not a function when I study the logger middleware

Tags: node.js, morgan

Hi I am learning the source code about [morgan](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan/blob/master/index.js#L151)

when I saw the line  `morgan.format('combined', ...)`
for my understand, why it can run success and not cause `morgan.format is not a function`. when I extract the main code run in my local and I got the error. 
how this place is implemented?

can anybody tell me ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the `module.exports` magic that makes the `format()` method accessible to the main `morgan()` function.

Here is a minimal reproduction:

```
module.exports = morgan
module.exports.format = format  // format() method is now available to morgan

function morgan() {}

morgan.format()  // Hello from format()

function format() {
  console.log('Hello from format()')
}
```

In short, `module.exports.some_method = some_method` add the `some_method()` function to the main module.